# Sharepoint Online List - Format Column/Row to be Red on certain Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I do not know JSON, so I am struggling to figure this out. I have a drop down menu column and if the user selects one of the drop down menus (Lets say its called "Peer Review - Rushed") I would like the cell to show red, or even the whole row if need be. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you need this in only the Modern UI, or both in Classic UI and Modern UI? JSON only works with the Modern UI.

Comment: Mike, I think just modern.

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP Just kidding, apparently people are using the classic, am I SOL because of this?

Comment: No, just need a different solution. Classic uses JSLink. If no one else does... I'll try to post an example this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Modern UI and JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Peer Review - Rushed', 'Red', if(@currentField == 'Peer Review - Slow', 'Blue', 'Black'))"
  }
}
```

This will set Red, Blue, or if other Black.

- Click the column heading's dropdown
- Click Column Settings.
- Click Format this column.
- Copy and paste the JSON and click Save.